# Is it possible to share mouse and keyboard over WAN?

Tags: synergy, wan

At my office I'm using two computers, which is connected to two different LANs. I'm looking for an application to share the mouse and keyboard from one of the computers with the other one.

I know of applications like Synergy, Input Director and Mouse Without Borders, but as far as I know they only work when the computers are on the same LAN.

Is it possible to make some of these applications work via WAN or is it possible with another application?

Comment: You should check with your IT department. These might be airgapped for reason.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1801462/1283699
(Not enough reputation comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a SSH-Tunnel and then connect Synergy through that. It is not exactly fast, but generally usable.

It was described in the old FAQ: http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/security.html

Btw: You can also use synergy "unprotected" over a WAN, it works if there are no firewalls blocking you. In any case (also with SSH) you would of course need either static IPs or something like dyndns if you do not want to change the ip to connect to manually.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a machine on the Internet that you can use for bouncing the data on you can use this solution:

Server:

```
ssh -N -R 24800:127.0.0.1:24800 -R 24801:127.0.0.1:24801 user@bounceserver
```

Client:

```
ssh -N -L 24800:127.0.0.1:24800 -L 24801:127.0.0.1:24801 user@bounceserver
```

In the client you connect to `127.0.0.1`.
And make sure both client and server use port 24800 (in some cases it's configured for 14800).