# Is there a way to share mouse/keyboard over WAN?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, network-shares, synergy, kvm-switch

I'm trying to share my mouse and keyboard between my laptop and PC. The issue is both are connected to university WiFi (Glide) and I'm pretty sure LAN security is tight. I've tried various software: Synergy, Barrier, LogiOptions... None work because they're designed to work on a Local Area Network. I was wondering if there was something I can do to have this work over WAN... It's the only plausible solution I'm seeing.

All questions welcome.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Would a remote desktop connection work? If so, try Teamviewer.

Comment: To get it to work over a WAN, you'd need access to the router/gateway/firewall to set up port forwarding. You're going to have to look for another solution.

Comment: It might be possible to use a VPN services such as LogMeIn's VPN service `Hamachi` to get both computers in a new LAN environment. Then you can use software such as Synergy.

Comment: @LPChip this was the perfect solution. Managed to link up to three separate devices with Hamachi using Synergy. Presumably would work just as seamlessly with other share mouse software. Cheers dude!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I've posted an answer so you can mark this as solved. That'll let others know you no longer need help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to bridge multiple networks and use them as one local network so you can use software like synergy.

The way to do this, is by using software that creates a local network through a VPN. One example of such is LogMeIn's Hamachi. One computer sets up as a server, and the others connect to it to create a new network with its own ip range.

This was originally designed to use LAN games over internet, but it will work for LAN utilities such as Synergy too.

Hamachi has an added bonus that it routes everything through the internet servers so no portforwarding is required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a screen-sharing product that works via the internet.

One computer act as server and the other as client, both establishing
their connection via the website of the chosen product.

An example is
[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/)
and its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/).

Answer (score -1):

I tried Hamachi, cooperate with https://www.sharemouse.com/ and https://www.inputdirector.com/. But the disadvantage is that the speed is too slow, so the mouse movement lag.
Update: If you are in China, you can use https://pgy.oray.com/download/personal/ this software, speed is quicker.